# Why does docall use go panic in singleflight?

Tags: go

I was recently reading the singleflight source code and I was puzzled by [line 158](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sync/+/refs/tags/v0.2.0:singleflight/singleflight.go;l=158;bpv=0).

```
if len(c.chans) > 0 {
    go panic(e)
    select {} // Keep this goroutine around so that it will appear in the crash dump.
} else {
    panic(e)
}
```

Why use go panic instead of direct panic when using channel? Use go docall on [line 129](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sync/+/refs/tags/v0.2.0:singleflight/singleflight.go;l=129;bpv=0), panic in this method, the upper layer cannot recover, so go panic should be meaningless, right?

Furthermore, if there are concurrent requests, the channel is still not written after the panic, won't other goroutines also block? If someone with good intentions reads and answers, I am very grateful~

Understand design implications

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`go panic` will result in a panic that cannot be recovered from. The panic and the `select` after it ensures that the panicking goroutine appears in the stack dump, so you can look at the stack dump and realize that a situation that should not have happened has happened.

This is simply a way to ensure that you do not unintentionally recover from something that should not be recovered from.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the design idea of ​​go panic, but in line 129, even if panic is used directly in go g.doCall(c, key, fn), other goroutines cannot recover, so I understand that the functions of go panic and panic should be identical.

Comment: There is one invocation of `doCall` that is called within the calling goroutine, so maybe because of that? I can only guess.

Comment: emm.. sry, i still don't understand. I think `panic`can replace `go panic`

Comment: If you panic, the caller has a chance to recover if `docall` was not called as `go docall`, which appears at least once. `go panic` and then `select{}` ensures that program panics, and that in the stack dump you have the goroutine that called `go panic`.

Comment: oh got it.On line 129,it's no problem.